# Failed to introspect annotated annotated methods on class org.springframework.orm.jpa.support .PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a webapp which gives this error on starting up . **Like the solutions here suggested i did add spring-beans dependency but it still shows the same error . I am even using the same spring versions.**

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:135)
```

My mvn:dependency:Dverbose result

```
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.14:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.14:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.03:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- servlets.com:cos:jar:05Nov2002:compile
[INFO] +- snapdeal.catalog.client:catalog-client:jar:5.4-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- com.snapdeal.catalog:base:jar:4.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2.1.RELEASE)
[INFO] |     +- (org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.11)
[INFO] |     +- (org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.5)
[INFO] |     +- org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (com.snapdeal:elasticMemcacheClient:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.snapdeal.sacs:SnapdealSACSClient:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:jar:1.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.46:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.10)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- ca.juliusdavies:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- (xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.10)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.10)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.4)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.1.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.snapdeal.sacs:SnapdealSACSBase:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (snapdeal.base:SnapdealBase:jar:4.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.1.1.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:runtime - omitted for conflict with 3.0.5.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.6.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- snapdeal.base:SnapdealBase:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:runtime - omitted for conflict with 4.0.1.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.11:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.5)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.14)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.4.1)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.4.1)
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.6.3)
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jibx:jibx-run:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:2.2.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.2.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scannotation:scannotation:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.10)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3)
[INFO] |  |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-spring:jar:2.2.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:2.2.1.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.2.1.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jettison-provider:jar:2.2.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:2.2.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     +- (javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.stream:sjsxp:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:jar:2.6.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2.14)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4)
[INFO] |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.44-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.1:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.1:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO] |  +- cryptix:cryptix:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-lgpl:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-lgpl:jar:1.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-lgpl:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-api:jar:1.0.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.5)
[INFO] |  +- com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-api:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-collectionschema:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-api:jar:1.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-runtime:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-api:jar:1.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-collectionschema:jar:1.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1-beta-6:compile - omitted for cycle)
[INFO] |  |  +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.0-FCS:compile - omitted for cycle)
[INFO] |  |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4.01)
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.6.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4.01)
[INFO] |  +- org.kubek2k:springockito-annotations:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.snapdeal:elasticMemcacheClient:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:jar:5.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.drools:knowledge-api:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.drools:drools-compiler:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.drools:drools-core:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.1.0.drools16:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.drools:knowledge-api:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.drools:knowledge-internal-api:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (org.drools:knowledge-api:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2)
[INFO] |  |  +- (antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:3.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.1.0.drools16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.drools:drools-decisiontables:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.drools:drools-core:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.drools:drools-compiler:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.drools:drools-templates:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.drools:drools-core:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.drools:drools-compiler:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:jar:2.6.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.ruedigermoeller:fst:jar:1.35:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.snapdeal.mail:mail-client:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.snapdeal.mail:base:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2.16)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-core:jar:1.0.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-api:jar:1.0.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.5)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-collectionschema:jar:1.0.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.5)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-runtime:jar:1.0.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.5)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4)
[INFO] |  +- com.snapdeal.mail:config-client:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.snapdeal.mail:base:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.snapdeal.mail:config-client-interface:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (com.snapdeal.mail:base:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.snapdeal.mail:report-client:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.snapdeal.mail:base:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.snapdeal.mail:report-client-interface:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (com.snapdeal.mail:base:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4.3)
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.3.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.3.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.3.0)
[INFO] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- (com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4)
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.10:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9.1)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- snapdeal.oms.client:SnapdealOMSClient:jar:7.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- snapdeal.oms.base:SnapdealOMSBase:jar:7.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-codegen:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-model:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-model-json:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.7.9:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.4)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-compiler:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-parser:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- (org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- (org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- (org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  \- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- (org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     \- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5.1)
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5.1)
[INFO] |  |  |        \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-core:jar:1.0.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-api:jar:1.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-collectionschema:jar:1.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-runtime:jar:1.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
```

I have tried every combination of version for spring and hibernate but still not able to solve it . Does it have to do anything with me using spring 4 as its Java Config based

Comment: As stated in the previous (and same!) question add the correct dependency and versions. Your dependencies are a mess. Check what is used with `mvn dependency:tree` and fix errors in there. You aren't using the versions you think you are using.

Comment: @M.Deinum i have indeed seen the dependency tree in eclipse and everywhere i am using 4.1.6 version of the spring-beans . Can you please specify which of the dependency's version is wrong ?

Comment: Don't look at a single dependency look at all spring jars, also try to use the command line version, that is easier/better then the eclipse one (IMHO that is).

Comment: @M.Deinum i am sorry but i have never read a dependency tree before . SO i edited the question to show my dependency tree . In all the omissions for spring-beans it says that it has been omitted for being a duplicate which shouldn't be the problem ? Also if you can share a link where i can read about resolving conflicts it would be great . As i couldn't find a good one

Comment: @M.Deinum i see that some of my dependencies are using spring-data-commons-1.5.1RELEASE  , spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1 RELEASE and spring-jms3.2.8 . Can this be the reason as from what i read NoUniqueBeanFound class is in spring-beans jar